# Separating contextual-links CSS, out of the CSS of menus and other associated markup

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

The following problem happens when you style menus in Drupal, using CSS. The problem is especially dominant when you edit the `<a>` tags of a menu, but happens in regards to all of the menu markup.

The following images describe problems for two different menus, in which CSS directives I gave to my `#navigation` selector and its `<a>` tags, such as `height: 60px`, `display: inline-block`, and `color: #fff`, are inherited by the contextual links markup and thus destroy its appearance and making it impractical if not nonfunctional.

Thus, the solution I need is to separate the contextual links CSS from the themes', loading it afterwards or hardcoded somehow.

I dedicate this question to experienced themers: How can one load the contextual links with "hardcoded" CSS code, so they won't inherit anything from CSS directives I write in any theme-dependent CSS.

[image]

[image]

### Code information:

Twig data:

```
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="menu">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set classes = [
          'menu-item',
          item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
          item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Mobile-first responsive CSS:

```
#navigation {height: auto; padding: 10px 0 10px 0; background: #0a97b7}
    #navigation ul {display: none} /*For JS conditioning: if none than...*/
    #navigation li {display: block}
        #navigation a {color: #fff}
            #navigation a:hover {text-decoration: none}
    .navtoggle {display: block; padding: 10px 25px 10px 0; font-size: 24px; background: none !important}
```

Desktop level CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
    #navigation {height: 60px; padding: 0}
        #navigation ul {display: block}
            #navigation li {display: inline-block}
                #navigation a {height: 60px; line-height: 60px; padding: 0 15px 0 15px; display: inline-block}
                /*<a> must be either block/inline-block to have its height changed.*/
                    #navigation a:hover {background: #55cfd6; text-decoration: none}
    #navigation .menu-item {display: inline-block; float: right}
    #navigation .is-active {background: #55cfd6}
    .navtoggle {display: none !important}
}
```

Complete reset of the contextual links class as follows, isn't effective (nor it is adequate) and is overridden by more specific codes:

```
.contextual ul       {background: #fff !important}
.contextual li       {display: block !important}
.contextual a        {color: black !important; height: auto !important; line-height: 1.3em !important; background: #fff !important}
.contextual a:hover  {background: #f4f4f4 !important}
```

**Every in-place menu seems better with this compelete reset, but it still don't cover all menus.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it like that `#id a { ... }` it will affect all the `<a>`'s of all the child divs that are inside the wrapper. Since the contextual links are inside it, they get affected.

[image]

Ex: if you do `html a { color: purple;}` since everything is a child of HTML, every single `<a>` gets affected.

In CSS there is no such command to affect all children except some child.

**In CSS you have to affect all children, and then you can override a specific child** by placing `.somediv a { color: green; }` after.

Ex:

```
html a { color: blue; } // all divs become blue.
.somediv a { color green; } // changes somediv to green.
```

If you do the same command:

```
a { color: brown; }
a { color yellow; }
```

It applies the brown first, but then applies the yellow. So the yellow is the actual one that you see. This is why it's called **C**ascading **S**tyle **S**heets. It reads from the top to the bottom.

So in your case you currently have

```
.contextual a{ color: black; } // applies black 
#menu-id a{ color: orange; } // since contextual is inside #menu-id the orange gets applied, since this is last, you see orange on your screen.
```

#### Solution (In Theory):

You need to load the style sheet that contains the `.contextual` AFTER the style sheet that contains the `#menu-id`

So when your website loads, it will read like this

```
#menu-id a{ color: orange; } // contextual is orange because it's inside menu-id, so it inherits this command.
// bunch of other stuff in between
.contextual a{ color: black; } // contextual is black
```

Since black is last, you see black for contextual

But there is one problem, the **/core/themes/stable/css/contextual/contextual.theme.css** gets loaded before your theme. You would have to hack core so it loads this css file after your theme's .css file.

#### Alternative solution:

What you could do is find something that wraps around the tab only rather than something that wraps the entire menu, such as `.menu-item`

[image]

Comment: I know the hierarchy issue... I tried to duplicate contextual.theme.css to my sub-theme, and referenced to it from libraries.yml, then drush cr. Still no change, even this last-in-hierarchy file clashes with it's previous (the main sub-theme stylesheet).

Comment: @Benia I will re-look at this later, but perhaps you also need to load the quick edit module css file after your theme.

Answer (score 1):

All contextual links are wrapped in a `div.contextual`, whereas navigational menu items are usually wrapped in a `li.menu-item`.